# Histogram hover text for ggplot and plotly with time formatting

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, tooltip, time-format

I'm looking to plot a histogram of times in R with ggplot and plotly.  I have the times saved in seconds.  I would like the axis and tooltip/hover text to display the time in MM:SS format though.  I can get the axis to work (mostly - it only has 2 labels right now and I'm having trouble getting it to show more), but I cannot get the hover text to work.

Is this possible?  I've tried dozens of iterations of this, but here is what I have right now:

```
p2 <- df %>%
  mutate(time_formatted = gsub("^0+", "",
                               sprintf("%02d:%05.2f",
                                       floor(time_seconds/60),
                                       time_seconds %% 60))) %>%
  mutate(bucketed_time = floor(time_seconds)) %>%
  mutate(hover_text = paste0('Time: ', custom_labels(time_seconds))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time_seconds)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = mako_palette[50],
                 binwidth = 1,
                 position = 'dodge') +
  labs(title = 'Times Histogram')) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Count') + 
  scale_x_reverse(name = 'Time',
                  labels = custom_labels) +
  theme_minimal()

ggplotly(p2, dynamicTicks = FALSE, tooltip = 'text', originalData = TRUE, hoverinfo = 'text', text = ~hover_text) %>%
  config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
```

with the function:

```
custom_labels_bucketed <- function(x) {
  minutes <- floor(x / 60)
  seconds <- x %% 60
  sprintf("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
}
```

Per the comments, I've edited to try to share a sample:

```
structure(list(time_seconds = c(60.46, 50.84, 64.54, 54.1, 59.21, 
73.45, 40.39, 38.31, 69.11, 74.17), name = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
"H", "I", "J")), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you make your example reproducible by sharing some sample data? `dput()` is the nicest way to share data as it is copy/pasteable and includes all data structure info, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows of `your_data`.

Comment: So, when I run your code I get an error with the custom labeler because of numeric rather than integer intermediate results. Changing to `sprintf("%d:%02d", as.integer(minutes), as.integer(seconds))` fixes that.

Comment: As for your hover text, the `?ggplotly` help page describes the `tooltip` argument as *"a character vector specifying which aesthetic mappings to show in the tooltip."* Since you haven't mapped `aes(text = ....)` in your plot, it's no surprise that `tooltip = 'text'` does nothing. Adding `text = hover_text` inside your `aes()` call gets the hovertext to display, but it seems like it messes with the histogram... the bars look skinnier, though maybe that's just due to the data granularity and small data sample? That exhausts my knowledge of plotly, but maybe it works for you?